# Windows Service and Gmail

Tags: c#, oauth, gmail, gmail-api

I am trying to run a windows service to fetch messages from a specific account that is unattended.
I have used the Gmail API but the drawback is that the token is not renewed and then there is a need some times for some human interaction. 
Is there a way to manage fetching messages from gmail unattended - no human interaction?